# Unexpected behavior with on.exit(..., add = TRUE)

Tags: r

First, please note that the following code creates and removes a folder in the current directory.  If it conflicts with any of your file names, don't run this code.  I'm not sure how to explain this question without it.

In `fun1` I use `on.exit(..., add = TRUE)` on one line, and on the next I try to remove the directory I created with another `on.exit` call.  It doesn't work.

```
fun1 <- function(){
   if(!file.exists("Rsaber")) dir.create("Rsaber")
   on.exit(file.remove(paste0("Rsaber/", list.files("Rsaber"))), add = TRUE)
   on.exit(file.remove("Rsaber"))
   write.csv("1,2,3,4", file = "Rsaber/new.csv")
}
> fun1()
# Warning message:
# In file.remove("Rsaber") :
#   cannot remove file 'Rsaber', reason 'Directory not empty'
> file.exists("Rsaber")
# [1] TRUE
> list.files("Rsaber")
# [1] "new.csv"
```

However, this method works.

```
fun2 <- function(){
   if(!file.exists("Rsaber")) dir.create("Rsaber")
   on.exit(file.remove(c(paste0("Rsaber/", list.files("Rsaber"))), "Rsaber"))
   write.csv("1,2,3,4", file = "Rsaber/new.csv")
}
> fun2()
> file.exists("Rsaber")
# [1] FALSE
```

This second method is also much cleaner and probably the way to go, but

**Why doesn't** `on.exit(..., add = TRUE)` **behave as expected in** `fun1` ?

Note that I'm not using a temporary directory here because this is part of a larger function  that has a logical argument for determining whether or not to keep a downloaded data file.

System info:

```
> version[[1]]
# [1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
```

Comment: Are you on windows? On windows an empty directory is not considered a file.

Comment: Why create a folder in the current directory instead of just using a temporary directory given by `tempdir`?

Comment: @jdharrison - system info added, @Dason - because the function that this process will be going into will have a `destroy` argument for asking the user whether they wish to keep a downloaded data file.

Comment: The add parameter isn't saying "I want to add more later" - it's saying "this call is adding to a previous call".  Put it on the second call to on.exit instead of the first.

Comment: `unlink` could be useful.

Comment: @Dason Yep, switched it all to tempfiles and tempdirs and it seems okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `add=TRUE` on the second `file.remove` otherwise the second statement replaces the first:

```
fun1 <- function(){
   if(!file.exists("Rsaber")) dir.create("Rsaber")
   on.exit(file.remove(paste0("Rsaber/", list.files("Rsaber"))))
   on.exit(file.remove("Rsaber"), add = TRUE)
   write.csv("1,2,3,4", file = "Rsaber/new.csv")
}
```

Also as noted this wont work on windows as the directory will not be considered as a file.

For cross-platform support maybe consider `unlink`

```
fun1 <- function(){
  if(!file.exists("Rsaber")) dir.create("Rsaber")
  on.exit(unlink("Rsaber", recursive = TRUE))
  write.csv("1,2,3,4", file = "Rsaber/new.csv")
  print(system('ls'))
}
```

Comment: Wow, I wish I could down-vote my own question.  I've thought it was the other way round forever!

Comment: Well it maybe useful as you identified a possible portability problem if you want to run your package cross-platform.

Comment: Yeah, and that is actually much more important.  Might have to go with `tempdir` after all

Comment: Maybe use `unlink` instead of `file.remove`